# JSON attributes from API POST are visible but not accessible with axios

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios

I am sending a `POST` request to the endpoint that serves my landing page using `axios`:

```
const json = await axios.post('/', {withCredentials: true});
```

This seems to work fine when I inspect what's returned with `console.log`. These debugging commands

```
console.log(json.status)
console.log(json.data)
```

produce this output in my browser terminal:

```
200
> Landing.js:42 {email: "me@example.ventures", name: "Aaron", profile_pic: "https://my_pic_url.photo.jpg"}
```

This all seems pretty straightforward, so it's melting my brain that I'm unable to access the properties of `json.data` as I would expect. For example, with `console.log(json.data.email)` I get:

```
> Landing.js:42 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
    at Landing (Landing.js:42)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14803)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17482)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18596)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23203)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22157)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22130)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:21756)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21188)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:24373)
    at react-dom.development.js:24758
    at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:21903)
    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:24757)
    at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:24840)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.js:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object.1 (serviceWorker.js:141)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.chunk.js:1
```

Even more confusing, I can call `console.log(JSON.stringify(json.data));` to get:

```
'{"email": "me@example.ventures", name: "Aaron", "profile_pic": "https://my_pic_url.photo.jpg"}'
```

`console.log(Object.keys(json))` prints

```
> (6) ["data", "status", "statusText", "headers", "config", "request"]
```

but weirdly, `console.log(Object.keys(json.data))` also errors out:

```
Landing.js:42 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at Landing (Landing.js:42)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14803)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17482)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18596)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23203)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22157)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22130)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:21756)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21188)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:24373)
    at react-dom.development.js:24758
    at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:21903)
    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:24757)
    at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:24840)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.js:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object.1 (serviceWorker.js:141)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.chunk.js:1
```

Note that I am using `useState` hooks inside of a function to store and access the data from my API calls. Perhaps that has something to do with it?

This seems like a very fixable issue, but I've been hung up on it for an hour or so now. Any help would be super-appreciated.

**UPDATE*

One more data point. Calling

```
const json_string = JSON.stringify(json.data);
console.log(JSON.parse(json_string))
```

produces the error:

```
> VM855:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Landing (Landing.js:43)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14803)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17482)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18596)
```

Screenshot from browser for `console.log(json.data)` and `console.log(typeof json.data)`: 
[image]

Per other Stack users' requests, here some screenshots from my Network inspector. The response looks great to me...:

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: what is the type of json.data: `console.log(typeof json.data);`

Comment: That means `data` is `null`. When you debug issues like this it's important to actually look at the response independently of your specific client code to isolate the cause of the issue (for example check the network tab in your browser)

Comment: Can you post the image of what you get in browser console on doing: `console.log(json.data)` and `console.log(typeof json.data)`

Comment: Thanks, @AluanHaddad. Took your recommendation and inspected the Network requests section. The response is coming in exactly as I expect it to.

Comment: @palaѕн thanks, see above

Comment: I am not sure how is this possible. Only thing I think of is you are calling `json.data` & `json.data.email` in different places. Do you get the issue when you call them together like after ajax call like `console.log( json.data, json.data.email )` or `console.log( json.data ); console.log( json.data.email )`?

Comment: @palaѕн puzzling, right? and yes, I am calling them in the same place and when I call `console.log( json.data, json.data.email )` I get the same error...

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined`